# Alert style iOS notifications (like messages) causes real time Game Center match to stop receiving messages

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

For some reason, when iOS alert style notifications pop up during a real time match (message, alarm etc..), the match ceases to receive data from opponents. The app itself functions, but there is no data transmission between players.

The delegate does not receive call backs from `match:(GKMatch *)match player:(NSString *)playerID didChangeState:(GKPlayerConnectionState)state` or `authenticationChanged`, so it appears that the players are both still connected to the match.

This issue occurs whether the user dismisses the alert style notification, or opens it.

Any thoughts on why/how this is happening and how I can prevent/recover from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of debugging, research and frustration, I came across my issue.

Since disconnects and resigning active are likely events with mobile devices & Game Center, I am using a data queue to send messages. It works by stacking the current message on the queue (and sending the message if it's the only message) and runs through the following data transmittal steps: 1) Send oldest message in queue, 2) wait for opponent receipt confirmation, 3) remove oldest message from queue, 4) if queue count is still > 0, send oldest message in queue...

For certain data types, however, we want to bypass the queue and not ask for receipt confirmation. One such instance is when we send messages to the opponent regarding application notifications `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` and `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`. However, even though the message didn't ask for receipt confirmation, I forgot to bypass the queue. Since the opponent never sent back a receipt confirmation, the `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` message was blocking the queue indefinitely.

I bypassed the queue appropriately and the game now resumes without issue. If anyone wants to see the actual code involved, I will be happy to share.